# How multiple file format supporting converters work?

Tags: ffmpeg, architecture, converters, imagemagick-convert, avconv

Software like ffmpeg/avconv, imagemagick convert.

Do they use an intermediate format:

```
format1 -> I. F.
format2 -> I. F.
I. F. -> format2
I. F. -> format3
...
```

Or do they have a *method* for converting from and to each supported format:

```
format1 -> format2
format1 -> format3
format2 -> format1
format2 -> format3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Detailed-description):

> **The decoder produces uncompressed frames (raw video/PCM audio/...)**
>   which can be processed further by filtering. After filtering, the
>   frames are passed to the encoder, which encodes them and outputs
>   encoded packets. Finally those are passed to the muxer, which writes
>   the encoded packets to the output file.
>
> The transcoding process in `ffmpeg` for each output can be described by
>   the following diagram:
>
> ```
>  _______              ______________
> |       |            |              |
> | input |  demuxer   | encoded data |   decoder
> | file  | ---------> | packets      | -----+
> |_______|            |______________|      |
>                                            v
>                                        _________
>                                       |         |
>                                       | decoded |
>                                       | frames  |
>                                       |_________|
>  ________             ______________       |
> |        |           |              |      |
> | output | <-------- | encoded data | <----+
> | file   |   muxer   | packets      |   encoder
> |________|           |______________|
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Decoder and encoders are separate. The intermediate format is uasually just refured to as “raw”. It’s is the format that is actually displayed.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick uses delegate libraries to convert between formats. For example libtif for TIFF and libpng for PNG, etc. Some format conversion is built directly into ImageMagick.